# How to fetch email from Facebook API, when user used their mobile no. for login?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Iam using facebook login for android app. I Am getting email and other details using Facebook API. I have following questions:

1) How to fetch email from Facebook API, when user used their mobile no. for login.

2) How we know that the user logged in with mobile number or email in Facebook login API in android?

Please Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user email id which user has used in facebook by:-

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            String email = object.getString("email");

                        }
                    });
```

You can redirect to another activity by:-

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //call your activity here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());

        }
    };
```

Comment: i have done this and am getting email id also?From here how i can redirect to my activity?and if the user logged in with mobile number then we wont get email id na?so how can add input field for it?

Comment: you can call another activity in FacebookCallback<LoginResult> OnSuccess method

Comment: Have u tried to get email id when user login with mobile no.?

Comment: we can't check whether user has logged in with email or mobile no.

Comment: The only possible way is to get the email after user has login

Comment: I have done it.  if (json.has("email")) {redriect to your activity}else{just create an input area to enter email id and then redirect.}

Answer (score 0):

If the user logged in with his mobile phone, you will not get an email. You can present an input field and ask the user for his email right after login.

Comment: Thanx.How can i redirect it to that input field?

Comment: just do it right after login. that should be no problem for an android developer.